# Can "a one" be an unambiguous substitution of "a [noun]"?

Tags: indefinite-article, ambiguity

I want to use "a one" in the following sentence to refer to *a single coat*:

> I heard that coats were invented for this reason and therefore wearing **a one** will surely keep you warm.

Does "one" take an article in this specific usage as it can be substituted with "a coat"? And, would it sound unambiguous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use only "one". The article "a" functions (weakly) as a numeral also, so you will have an unpleasant redundancy in the sentence.

> I heard that coats were invented for this reason and therefore wearing **one** will surely keep you warm.

---

"One" substitutes "a coat", not "coat". This is an additional reason why "a" is not needed.

---

"A one" is not usable in any situation (at least, I cannot think of one right now).

Comment: You can say *"wearing [**such a one**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/such%20a%20one) will surely . . ."* *Such a one* is an acceptable pronoun phrase.

Comment: It is possible in combination with an adjective, e.g. "a new one", "a yellow one".

Comment: Depending on the context, "a new one" and "a yellow" are fine. "A one" is never fine.